# best way to wrap opengl models

Tags: opengl, game-engine

**In short:** What is the "preferred" way to wrap OpenGL's buffers, shaders and/or matrices required for a more high level "model" object?

I am trying to write this tiny graphics engine in C++ built on core OpenGL 3.3 and I would like to implement an as clean as possible solution to wrapping a higher level "model" object, which would contain its vertex buffer, global position/rotation, textures (and also a shader maybe?) and potentially other information.

I have looked into [this open source engine, called GamePlay3D](https://github.com/gameplay3d/GamePlay) and don't quite agree with many aspects of its solution to this problem. Is there any good resource that discusses this topic for modern OpenGL? Or is there some simple and clean way to do this?

Comment: Can you tell us which aspects of GamePlay3D you don't agree with?

Comment: I noticed that you say that you are creating a graphics engine. Do you have any experience building something which you would use the engine for? I ask this because it is a common pattern for developers to get sucked into framework/engine development as a way of avoiding app/game development.

Comment: i agree and have already personally went through those roadblocks in development =) but after research on possible replacement of this homebuilt engine i came to the conclusion that adding other people's libraries that enforce certain limitations as it is the case with a graphics engine is quite harmful to achieving a clean, reusable code base which is just something i value a lot. Also, this engine i plan to make is supposed to be minimalistic and i am developing other parts of my bigger project at the same time.

Comment: @Jerem there are a few points i disagree with GamePlay3D about, i just thought it would be too much to write and too debatable but i'll try to explain here. GamePlay3D  tries to be more than just a graphics engine, including sounds and physics libraries - my goals are to keep it clean. And after looking into some examples of apps built in it, i saw how many high level objects still have to be configured on a rather low level, while my goal is to simplify and give the app developer a more abstract programming interface. In a way I would say my mindset is inspired by that of arch linux on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends a lot on what you want to be able to do with your engine. Also note that these concepts are the same with DirectX (or any other graphic API), so don't focus too much your search on OpenGL. Here are a few points that are very common in a 3D engine (names can differ):

**Mesh:**
A mesh contains submeshes, each submesh contains a vertex buffer and an index buffer. The idea being that each submesh will use a different material (for example, in the mesh of a character, there could be a submesh for the body and one for the clothes.)

**Instance:**
An instance (or mesh instance) references a mesh, a list of materials (one for each submesh in the mesh), and contains the "per instance" shader uniforms (world matrix etc.), usually grouped in a uniform buffer.

**Material:** (This part changes a lot depending on the complexity of the engine). A basic version would contain some textures, some render states (blend state, depth state), a shader program, and some shader uniforms that are common to all instances (for example a color, but that could also be in the instance depending on what you want to do.)

More complex versions usually separates the materials in *passes* (or sometimes *techniques* that contain *passes*) that contain everything that's in the previous paragraph. You can check [Ogre3D documentation](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_14.html#Material-Scripts) for more info about that and to take a look at one possible implementation. There's also a very good article called *Designing a Data-Driven Renderer* in [GPU PRO 3](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781439887820) that describes an even more flexible system based on the same idea (but also more complex).

**Scene:** (I call it a *scene* here, but it could really be called anything). It provides the shader parameters and textures from the environment (lighting values, environment maps, this kind of things).

And I thinks that's it for the basics. With that in mind, you should be able to find your way around the code of any open-source 3D engine if you want the implementation details.

Comment: this answer is exactly what i was looking for yet, slightly unrelated, how does this work with a deferred rendering approach? since rendering is then done into framebuffers, would this answer's structure still be valid for the most part? or what would be the core differences?

Comment: on another matter, how modern is this answer's approach? when was this structure popularized and aren't there newer ways that use OpenGL 3.3 to its fullest?

Comment: @nOvoid: It would be the same for a deferred renderer. The only difference is that you don't store lighting information in the Scene (but a scene could still be there to provide other info).

I have no idea when it's got popularized but as far as I can tell, there is no _more modern_ way to organize model data in a generic way. Now, what I described here is very vague and the _modernity_ probably depends a lot more on how the engine is implemented (for example, instancing is a very important technique nowadays, but it has to be added on top of what I described.)

Answer (score 2):

This is in addition to Jerem's excellent answer.

At a low level, there is no such thing as a "model", there is only buffer data and the code used to process it.  At a high level, the concept of a "model" will differ from application to application.  A chess game would have a static mesh for each chess piece, with shared textures and materials, but a first-person shooter could have complicated models with multiple parts, swappable skins, hit boxes, rigging, animations, et cetera.

#### Case study: chess

For chess, there are six pieces and two colors.  Let's over-engineer the graphics engine to show how it could be done if you needed to draw, say, thousands of simultaneous chess games in the same screen, instead of just one game.  Here is how you might do it.

- Store all models in one big buffer.  This buffer has all of the vertex and index data for all six models clumped together.  This means that you never have to switch buffers / VAOs when you're drawing pieces.  Also, this buffer never changes, except when the user goes into settings and chooses a different style for the chess pieces.
- Create another buffer containing the current location of each piece in the game, the color of each piece, and a reference to the model for that piece.  This buffer is updated every frame.
- Load the necessary textures.  Maybe the normals would be in one texture, and the diffuse map would be an array texture with one layer for white and another for black.  The textures are designed so you don't have to change them while you're drawing chess pieces.
- To draw all the pieces, you just have to update one buffer, and then call `glMultiDrawElementsIndirect()`... *once per frame*, and it draws all of the chess pieces.  If that's not available, you can fall back to `glDrawElements()` or something else.

#### Analysis

You can see how this kind of design won't work for everything.

- What if you have to stream new models into memory, and remove old ones?
- What if the models have different size textures?
- What if the models are more complex, with animations or forward kinematics?
- What about translucent models?
- What about hit boxes and physics data?
- What about different LODs?

The problem here is that your solution, and even the very concept of what a "model" is, will be very different depending on what your needs are.

Comment: while i think you made a good point on the potential complexity of a graphics engine, what i am trying to achieve is a good out-of-the-box usability, allowing many common use cases to be done easily and a robust, extensible code structure, allowing for LODs, translucency, etc to be added without much change on the existing system required.